# Issue with ImagePicker Controller UIBarButtonItem instad of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add uiimagepickercontroller to a VC but I chnage the button to bar button then
I got an error after change the btnClickMe for UIButton to UIBarButtonItem I didn't understand the Error what seems the problem ?

> value type UIBarButtonItem has no member 'Frame'

I deleted the frame but it didn't works

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClickMe: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
    var popover:UIPopoverController?=nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker!.delegate=self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openCamera()

        }
        let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openGallary()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
        {
            UIAlertAction in

        }

        // Add the actions
        picker?.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: alert)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openCamera()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            openGallary()
        }
    }
    func openGallary()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        print("picker cancel.")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPopoverController has been deprecated in iOS 9. Xcode probably shows this warning:

> 'UIPopoverController' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implementd as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController.

However, if you still want to use it, you need to use the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` method instead of `presentPopoverFromRect`, as UIBarButtonItems don't have a `frame` property.

Comment: Yes I got this error ,What shall I'll do to solve it?

Comment: I think Apple wants us to use `UIPopoverPresentationController`s instead. Here's the documentation. I think it works pretty similarly: http://apple.co/1L3CNki